# Block hotmal and live when when we use Microsoft IAM

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, identity-management

We have implemented Microsoft Identity Access Management in our web application login. But when we implement the same in our branches, users are able to login in their personal Hotmail account. As per organization policy personal account should not be accessed from branch outlet. Is the any option block all hotmail account and enable only company account.

login.microsoftonline.com

Comment: i guess at the app registration level you could restrict that ?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by ***Thomas***, you can block all Hotmail accounts and enable only company account **while registering the web application** in Azure AD.

Please check the **`supported account type`** you have selected while registering the web application in Azure AD.

To enable only company account, register web application by selecting supported account type as **"Single tenant"**

[image]

If you have selected **`Multitenant and personal Microsoft accounts`**, then users can login with Hotmail accounts. To block that, avoid selecting that option and choose **Single Tenant**.

**Reference:**

[Validation differences by supported account types - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/supported-accounts-validation)

Comment: The user can enter into his personal email by opening a new tab or browser window and going to login.microsoft.com. The given methods just stop using the user's personal ID on the application login redirection page. Organization not support internet in POS machines for this we enable login.microsoft.com in all POS machines. But now users are able to login to their personal account.